# Webpack 5 - ERROR in Error: Child compilation failed: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:4)

Tags: html, css, webpack, module, webpack-5

I don't understand what is the problem? Webpack does not compile the project and shows the following error:

```
ERROR in Error: Child compilation failed: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:4)
```

But I can't figure out where the error derives from, in which module or file, where to look for it? [This is the error from my IDE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuYLt.png)

At the moment, it gives only 1 error when compiling, before that there were 22 errors. Actions that could lead to this - [trying to solve the problem through CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG327.png).
After I removed everything in the code (`-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2`), the number of errors was reduced to 1, but I don’t understand what to do next.

My webpack 5 config: [webpack.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ugUN.png)

If someone knows how to solve this problem, or where to look for the root of evil, please help.

Comment: Without seeing the exact source file, it seems like it could be a [byte order mark issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2868). Try saving your file with UTF-8 encoding instead of what it currently is (most likely UTF-8 with BOM).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! It turned out that in my **webpack.config** in the image processor, I did not add **webp** support. And when I added it on the fly, the already assembled project did not take this moment into account. As a result, after restarting the build with the **npm run dev** command, the updated **webpack** config file started working as it should! Thank you all for your attention to the issue and the desire to help figure it out! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT9E9.png)